# Proof the existance of a certain function.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I want to solve the following problem:

1) Let $ a < b\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists $ f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $ f > 0$ in $ (a,b)$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $ x\notin(a,b)$.

2)Let $ a < b\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that here exists $ f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $0\le f\le 1$, $ f(x)=0$ for $x\le a$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ge b$.

3)Let $R>r>0$. Show that there exists $ f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f=1$ in $B_r(0)$ and supp $f = B_R(0)$

My attempt:

For one I have found the function $f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    e^{\frac{-1}{(x+b)^{2}}} e^{\frac{-1}{(x+a)^{2}}} & : x \in (a,b) \\
    0 & : x \notin (a,b)
  \end{array}
\right.
$

My problem is to find a strictly positive function and I think there is a mistake with the statement because I think we cant find a function $f$ that can be positive and $0$ is a differentiable manner, that is my problem.

For two I evoke the same function as above only I define the require one as:

$$F(x)=\frac{\int_a^x f}{\int_a^b f}$$

I think this should work.

And for 3) I want to use the following lemma:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ open and $C\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a compct such that $C\subset U$. Then there exists $\phi \in C^\infty$  such that $\phi =1$ in $C$ and supp$\phi \subset U$, but the thing is that I dont know how to aplly it to get the result, because I do not have any function in mind sucht it satisfies the condtions in 3)

Answer (score 1):

Define   $f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & x>0
   \end{cases}$

For part 1: $f(x-a)\cdot f(b-x)$

For part 2: $\frac{f(x-a)}{f(x-a)+f(b-x)}$

For part 3: let $h$ be the function from part 2, with $a=r^2$ and $b=R^2$, and then consider $1-h\big(|x|^2\big)$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Euclidean norm.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), but the last function is not in $R^n$ right?

Comment: If you want a function in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then consider $1-h(|x|^2)$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

Comment: And well my other question is, is it suffices with giving an explicit example rifgt?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The above example is explicit, no?

Comment: yes that is right I want to know if it is enough with that :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, then R and r are in $R^n$ right?, and how can you take the square root of a vector?

Comment: No, they are positive real numbers.

Comment: Ok, then how can it is posible to have a example in $R^n$ with real number, can explain this in detail please :)

Comment: $R$ and $r$ are positive real numbers, and you want to find a smooth function $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$ whenever $|x|<r$, and $f(x)>0$ precisely when $|x|<R$. This is what the question is asking. The $|x|$ denotes the n-dimensional Euclidean norm.

Comment: I am back I am sorry for the delay, but I was eating, then h(x) takes values in $R^{n}$ and so we are only summing a constant to the vector x right?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Well, How the function h(x) looks like (explicity)? :)

Comment: It looks like a smooth bump which is flat on the top.

Comment: Right but the analytic expression :), because I dont get it :) thanks

Comment: The function is $\frac{f(x_1^2+ \dots +x_n^2-r^2)}{f(x_1^2+...+x_n^2-r^2)+f(R^2-x_1^2+...-x_n^2)}$ where $f$ is the function defined in the answer above. Just write down the formula explicitly in terms of $e$ and whatnot.

Comment: Ok ;) I get it, one more thing the function of 1) has the requirements of the problem right ? Is because I am not sure about f>0 for x in (a,b)

Comment: Yes, I am sure of the answer. But if you are not sure of the answer, then don't use it. Remember, you should only use an answer if you fully understand it.

Comment: Ok :) thanks a lot I resoned something like your answer before (I wrote it my post) but that is why I wasnt quite sure about it :) now you tell me that the answer is right and that is enough for me because I have already attempt and I am happy to know that we both are right :)