# Proving a result concerning compact sets.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $C C,E\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $C$ is compact,$E$ is closed and $ C\cap E = \emptyset$. Show that there exist a compact set $D\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $ C\subset D^0$ (where $D^0$ is the interior) and $D \cap E = \emptyset$.

My attempt:

I want to use the following result:

Let $C \subset U \subset \mathbb{R^n} $, $C$ compact and $U$ open. Then there exists a compact $D$ such that $ C\subset D^0$ and $D \subset U$ and I want to take $U=E^{c}$ but the thing is how can I ensure that $C \subset U$ Can you help me to fix this problem please :) or Can you give an alternative proof ?   Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C \subset E^{c}$ because $C \cap E = \emptyset$.

Let $x \in C$ and suppose that $x\notin E^{c}$, this means $x \in C$ and $ x \in E$ i.e. $x \in C\cap E$ which is a contradiction. Thus $x \in C \subset E^{c}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, then the other workI did in this is right?

Comment: Well, it looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot because the part you prove here is the missing one, Can you help me with this question please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206046/proof-the-existance-of-a-certain-function/1206117?noredirect=1#comment2453904_1206117 THANKS IN ADVANCE :).